# Eclipse Debug Configuration Tab for Android

Tags: android

I read some advice about fixing the "Source not found issue" during debugging. 
The Advice is 
In this scenario just follow the following steps : 1) Go to Run->Debug Configurations 2)Select the remote application configuration being debugged. 3)Select the second tab named 'Source' 4)Now add the folder/projects containing the source code explicitly here.

However, I check the Debug Configuration I only see three tabs, Android, Target, Common.  I don't see any tab named Source .

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your application source, but the sources of the Android API. It's not included in the SDK download. So when the debugging goes to an Android class Eclipse will raise an error. You have to add them -> [read this](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/). Currently though, I am not sure if the Android repositories are available for checking out the source files.